# Streambuilder Null Error. Variable returning Null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am trying to pass a String variable into the Stream in the Streambuilder but it is returning the

'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 269 pos 10: 'data != null'' Error.

I have checked the variable and it is not returning a null value via print function.

```
class NoteStream extends StatefulWidget {
  final String reqDataBase;

  NoteStream({this.reqDataBase});

  @override
  _NoteStreamState createState() => _NoteStreamState();
}
class _NoteStreamState extends State<NoteStream> {
  String database;

  @override
  void initState() {
    database = '${widget.reqDataBase}Notes';
    print('Data is : $database');
    //I need to fix the database
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection(database).snapshots(),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't send data directly, you have to send it through a Text widget like below example

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection(database).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              /// While waiting for the data to load, show a loading spinner.
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              } else {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Text('No data to show');
                } else {
                  /// if we want to do some data manipulation we 
                  /// can do before it sending to a widget.
                  return Text(snapshot.data);
                }
              }
          }
        });
```